# Python3 - Как запустить строннее приложение в отдельном терминале и ждать его завершения?

Tags: python-3.x, консоль

Нужно запустить отдельное приложение в отдельном терминальном окне и ждать его закрытия. Делаю так:

```
result = subprocess.run(["xfce4-terminal", "-e", "./etherdump.sh"], capture_output=True)
```

пофигу, все стартует в отдельном окне, но и выполненеи скрипта идет дальше. Как мне заставить скрипт ждать закрытия терминала в таком случае?

Comment: Communicate посмотри

Comment: Не, это не помогает. Помогло заменить xfce4-terminal на xterm.